# Anko Layout DSL: How to use already existing layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

My problem is specifically connected to `constrainLayout { ... }`, but as [Anko Layout](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts-Examples) does not care it applies to every `Layout`.

I can do this:

```
// Could also be verticalLayout { ... } or any other Layout
constraintLayout {
    // some layout logic e.g.
    view {
        // ...
    }.lparams {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem because [this DSL](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/ConstraintLayout) creates a new `ConstraintLayout`, but I want to do the same logic with my already existing `ConstraintLayout`. I am searching for something like a "`dsl`" function, but I could not find anything in the documentation or anywhere else.

```
ConstraintLayout(this).dsl {
    // ...
}
```

There is the [`applyRecursively { ... }`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/d5a526512b48c5cd2e3b8f6ff14b153c2337aa22/anko/library/static/commons/src/Ui.kt#L32) function, which is used by the classes marked with `AnkoViewDslMarker`, i.e. in the layout DSL's, but that does not mark "my already existing `ConstraintLayout`" and thus I cannot use any of the DSL features.

So maybe a simple solution is marking my object with an `annotation class`, but I doubt that this works because I am using XML alongside, where "my already existing `ConstraintLayout`" also comes from. I hope someone knows how to do this with Anko. Otherwise I will have to file an issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved getting `ConstraintLayout` "lparams" by creating an extension function, which I can then use *like* the DSL:

```
inline fun View.constraintLparams(width: Int, height: Int, init: LayoutParams.() -> Unit) {
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(width, height)
    layoutParams.init()
    this.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the [`ankoView(...) { ... }`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/static/commons/src/Custom.kt#L35) function that you need, it allows you to use an arbitrary view provided by a function that you pass as the first argument in the same way as the views supported by Anko natively.

See its description here: [*Is it extensible?*](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#is-it-extensible)

Given that you have an existing `constraintLayout`, you can do something like this:

```
ankoView({ constraintLayout }) { 
    // Inner DSL scope for constraintLayout
}
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the point of the function. I am already forced to insert an `Int` for the theme and then the lambda is basically just the `init { ... }` function, but there is no DSL (as the type returned *and* used for the `init { ... }` function is the typed returned from the `factory { ... }` function).